Dependabot::NotImplemented in azure devops
I'm using dependabot from tingle software which is available in azure marketplace and I want it to be used for security updates alone but ended up in below error. For version updates, it is raising PR as expected and I used to follow this documentation - https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#configuration-options-for-the-dependabotyml-file
proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 [140] 200 http://host.docker.internal:35915/update_jobs/update_0_nuget_security_only/update_dependency_listupdater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> Dependabot::NotImplementedupdater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/updater.rb:36:in run' updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/update_files_command.rb:44:in block in perform_job'updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/vendor/ruby/3.3.0/gems/opentelemetry-api-1.4.0/lib/opentelemetry/trace/tracer.rb:37:in block in in_span' updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/vendor/ruby/3.3.0/gems/opentelemetry-api-1.4.0/lib/opentelemetry/trace.rb:70:in block in with_span'updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/vendor/ruby/3.3.0/gems/opentelemetry-api-1.4.0/lib/opentelemetry/context.rb:87:in with_value' updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/vendor/ruby/3.3.0/gems/opentelemetry-api-1.4.0/lib/opentelemetry/trace.rb:70:in with_span'updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/vendor/ruby/3.3.0/gems/opentelemetry-api-1.4.0/lib/opentelemetry/trace/tracer.rb:37:in in_span' updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/update_files_command.rb:18:in perform_job'updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> /home/dependabot/dependabot-updater/lib/dependabot/base_command.rb:37:in run' updater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 ERROR <job_update_0_nuget_security_only> bin/update_files.rb:46:in <main>'proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 [141] POST http://host.docker.internal:35915/update_jobs/update_0_nuget_security_only/record_update_job_error{"data":{"error-type":"unknown_error","error-details":{"message":"Dependabot::NotImplemented"}},"type":"record_update_job_error"}proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 [141] 200 http://host.docker.internal:35915/update_jobs/update_0_nuget_security_only/record_update_job_errorproxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 [142] PATCH http://host.docker.internal:35915/update_jobs/update_0_nuget_security_only/mark_as_processed{"data":{"base-commit-sha":"48833615b0f9d072ef767fd84f899a4109b5bfe8"},"type":"mark_as_processed"}proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 [142] 200 http://host.docker.internal:35915/update_jobs/update_0_nuget_security_only/mark_as_processedupdater | 2024/11/20 09:01:55 INFO Results:updater | Dependabot encountered '1' error(s) during execution, please check the logs for more details.updater | +---------------+updater | |    Errors     |updater | +---------------+updater | | unknown_error |updater | +---------------+proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:57 0/576 calls cached (0%)proxy | 2024/11/20 09:01:57 Skipping sending metrics because api endpoint is emptycli | 2024/11/20 09:01:58 updater failure: updater exited with code 1

I followed dependabot file instruction from this documentation for security updates - https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-security-updates/configuring-dependabot-security-updates#overriding-the-default-behavior-with-a-configuration-file
dependabot.yaml:- (security updates)
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "nuget"
    directory: /Engine
    labels:
      - "nuget"
      - "dependencies"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 0
    commit-message:
      prefix: "nuget"
      prefix-development: "nuget"
      include: "scope-and-version"
      separator: "-"
    groups:
      nuget:
        patterns:
          - "*"

dependabot-pipeline.yaml:-
trigger: none
schedules:
  - cron: 0 0 * * 1,3,5
    displayName: Every Monday,Wednesday,Friday at 05:30am IST
    branches:
      include:
        - develop
    always: true     

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: Dependabot
    displayName: Dependabot Execution
    timeoutInMinutes: 720
    steps:
    - script: |
        sudo cp -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.azuredevops/ /.azuredevops/
      displayName: Move Dependabot file

    - task: dependabot@2
      inputs:
        authorEmail: 'serviceaccount@domain.com'
        authorName: 'serviceaccount'
        azureDevOpsAccessToken: '$(System.AccessToken)'
        gitHubAccessToken: '$(GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN)'
      displayName: Run Dependabot

I have tried almost all the options here, none of them are working. I want dependabot to detect vulnerable package and raise PR for security updates alone. Right now, it is working fine for version updates in package manager npm, nuget & pip.
dependabot.yaml(version updates):-
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "nuget"
    directory: /Engine
    allow:
      - dependency-type: "direct" 
    target-branch: "develop"
    labels:
      - "nuget"
      - "dependencies"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 10
    commit-message:
      prefix: "nuget"
      prefix-development: "nuget"
      include: "scope-and-version"
      separator: "-"
    groups:
      nuget:
        patterns:
          - "*"

